# Why do we declare variables at the start of a module?

Tags: vba

As my first language and as completely taught from other's example I never questioned the standard practice in VBA of grouping all variable declarations at the start of the module, routine or function they are scoped to as in this example.

```
Sub Traditional()
Dim bVariable as Boolean
Dim OtherVariable
' Some code using OtherVariable goes here
'
' Now we use bVariable
bVariable = True
Do While bVariable
    bVariable = SomeFunction()
Loop
End Sub
```

Now I'm learning that standard practice in other languages is to declare variables as close to where they are used as possible, like this:

```
Sub Defensive()
Dim OtherVariable as String
' Some code using OtherVariable goes here
'
' Now we use bVariable
Dim bVariable as Boolean
bVariable = True
Do While bVariable
    bVariable = SomeFunction()
Loop
End Sub
```

This seems completely sensible to me as a defensive programming practice - in that it limits both span and live time (as explained in [Code Complete](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&pg=PT353&lpg=PT353&dq=span+live+time+programming+variable&source=bl&ots=RQvY2McKeD&sig=1y_vGZs74_54Ap7kUIS_2vcf5dY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HZrJUI_NPPPa0QWwiIDYAg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw)), so I'm wondering if there is any reason for not doing the same in VBA? Possible reasons I can think of are memory, running time (e.g. repeatedly declaring inside a loop), tradition - arguably a good reason as there must be hundreds of thousands of VBA programmers who expect to see all used variables at the start of the routine. Are there any I've missed that might explain the benefit of this practice or at least where it came from?

Comment: In VBA I've always declared variables at the top of the sub/function etc to make it easier for others to come behind me and debug / extend my code. Generally the people I do VBA for have little to no programming background.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it does help them though. If anything it makes it harder.

Comment: A little off-topic, but VBScript hoists variables to the top of the scope (global or function) just like Javascipt. So the following code wil run in VBScript: `Option Explicit:Msgbox i:Dim i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I declare all my variables at the top.  I think declaring them closer to first use masks (at least) two other problems that should be fixed first.

1. Procedures too long: If you're procedure is more than fits on a screen, perhaps it's doing too much and should be broken into smaller chunks.  You'll also find that unit tests are way easier to write when your procedures are small and only do one thing.
2. Too many variables: If you have a bunch of related variables, consider using a custom class module or user-defined type.  It will make the code more readable and easier to maintain.

If your procedures are short and you're using classes and UDTs, the benefits of declaring the variables at the point of use are lessened or eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

I think both way are just different coding style in VBA

In old C Standard, all Declaration must be on the top, I think many people just adopt this habit and bring it into other PL such as VBA.

Declaring variable on the top is clear for short list of variable names. It will be unreadable for a long list of variable name

Declaring variable close to where it's being used is introduced later. I think this practice has a clear advantage over "declare on the top" for PLs that has optimizer or more scope than VBA. (Like you can declare variables where the scope is visible in a FOR loop only) Then the optimizer will change the scope for you. (In VBA words, it may change a GLOBAL variable to a PROCEDURE variable)

For VBA, no perference

Comment: Totally agree that it's hard to keep track of with a long list of variables. Interesting history that it may spring from C Standard too. I'm tempted to keep the declarations at the top for shorter subroutines and functions but declare close to where it is used for longer ones - like a long main routine controlling the flow of a more complicated program.